# How to generate a shorter base64 string?

Tags: macos, shell, base64, fish

I am using

```
printf "%s%s" $url (date +%s) | base64
```

to generate a pseudo-unique string based on a URL and a time stamp:

```
cRH9qeL3XyVnaXJkppBuH20tf5JlcG9uFX1lL2IvdHRRRS9kMMQxOPLKNYIzQQ==
```

This is too long for me. Is there any way to *compress* or make the string just a bit shorter?

Notes: I am using the generated string to create a directory in the file system and I can't use the original URL because it contains slashes and other punctuation and I would like to keep the checks at a minimum. `base64` seems like a very easy solution to generate a uniform alpha-numeric character string. If only I could make it **shorter**.

Answer (score 2):

The base64 conversion of a given string will always be the same. There is no "shorter version" of base64. But what you can do is retrieve only the first characters of the base64 result; with `cut` for instance.

In this example, the final result will be the first 10 characters of the base64 conversion:

```
$> printf "%s%s" $url (date +%s) | base64 | cut -c -10
cRH9qeL3Xy
```

Using `cut` this way is also safe if the base64 result is shorter than 10 characters.

But be aware that by doing this, a base64 decode on the shortened string will not result in the original string.

Also, if you have multiple strings that are almost the same, there is a chance that the shortened base64 will be the same:

```
$> echo "http://www.google.com" | base64 | cut -c -10
aHR0cDovL3
$> echo "http://www.google.com/test" | base64 | cut -c -10
aHR0cDovL3
```

---

Another possibility, if you don't mind not being able to retrieve the original string from the encoded one, is to use a hash function, such as md5 or sha:

```
$> echo "http://www.google.com" | md5sum
b7d1c31f1654ddf1043260b571e9d8ba  -
$> echo "http://www.google.com" | md5sum | cut -c -10
b7d1c31f16
$> echo "http://www.google.com/test" | md5sum | cut -c -10
6d0238f364
```

Comment: The problem is the cut characters can repeat since the data in $url is sometimes similar.

Comment: I've just edited my answer with another solution using hash functions that could suit you better.

Comment: Nice, but the OP may not have `md5sum` installed.

Comment: If you assume that the user has `base64` installed, I think you can assume he has `md5sum` too !

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find md5sum installed anywhere. I am on OS X.

Comment: Well, it depends on your system. On Linux, it is already installed in most of the distributions. Apparently, on Mac OS X, this command is called `md5` (http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/13/check-md5-hash-on-your-mac/)

Comment: On Mac OS X you can use [`md5`](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Check-MD5-Sum-on-Mac-OS-X-431080.shtml). That's why it's always a good idea to tag your questions.